# Is there a way to find if a number is a perfect cube in python without using ** or pow()

Tags: python

I have an assignment where I need to find if a number is a perfect cube without using ** or pow() function in python

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: Yes, implement the algorithms that `pow` work on.

Comment: So, you can use multiplication sign then?

Comment: You can try to approximate the cube root with Newton's algorithm for finding  zeros.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Reworked for cubes.

What you can do is use the mathematical approach you'd most likely use the prime numbers and splitting in prime factors. This is what I implemented too.

First function will dynamically build up a list of primes using [Aristoteles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

```
primes_list = [2]

def add_primes():
    """ Function to expand the primes if we run out of them Aristoteles
    """
    length = primes_list[primes_list.__len__()-1]
    new_length = length*2
    for i in range(length, new_length):
        is_prime = True
        for prime in primes_list:
            if is_prime and i%prime == 0:
                is_prime = False
        if is_prime:
            primes_list.append(i)
```

Second just like in math I split up the number into it's [prime factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor)

```
def split_in_primes(number, found_primes=None):
    """ Function to split the number in primes
    """
    if found_primes is None:
        found_primes = []
    one_found = False
    for prime in primes_list:
        if number % prime == 0:
            number /= prime
            found_primes.append(prime)
            one_found = True
    if number > 1 and one_found:
        split_in_primes(number, found_primes)
    elif not one_found and number > 1:
        add_primes()
        split_in_primes(number, found_primes)
    return found_primes
```

As last I check if the prime factors come in multitudes of 3, so being a perfect cube:

```
def is_perfect_cube(number):
    """ Check if the number is a perfect cube
    """
    found_primes = split_in_primes(number)
    counts = []
    for prime in primes_list:
        counts.append(found_primes.count(prime))
    is_cube = True
    for count in counts:
        if count%3 != 0:
            is_cube = False
    return is_cube

for i in range(0, 50):
    print(str(i) + " is perfect cube? " + str(is_perfect_cube(i)))
```

**ALTERNATIVE AND BETTER!!** As pointed out in one of the comments this will be a lot more efficient if you re;ove split_in_primes and change iscube to:

```
def is_cube(number, start_index = 0):
    """ Function to split the number in primes
    """
    if number == 0:
        return False
    for prime in primes_list[start_index:]:
        start_index += 1
        count = 0
        while number % prime == 0:
            count += 1
            number /= prime
        if count != 0 and count%3 != 0:
            return False

    if number > 1:
        add_primes()
        is_cube(number, start_index)
    return True
```

This will check emmediatly if a certain prime is in it a multitude of 3 tested with 124925014999 (4999**3) And still goes fast

Comment: With the edit I hope this will help you @HasanJunaid

Comment: Also probably the splittign into primes and the counting could be done in one step, However this way will make 3 blocks that can have different purposesm Aristotel when you need priomesm splittign in primes for any power you have and perfect cube yeah I guess that one implements both others so only to find perfect cubes

Comment: Also: doubling the primes array might be a bad approuch as in the end numbers tend to come down very fast except if you enter a number conteining a big prime. So if you're certain the numbers are snall you can adjust the expontential growth to linear. For big numbers the exponential growth will push the limits of the recursion depth so potential you wish to even remove the recursion in it if you're doing very big numbers

Comment: yes indeed a better approach would be to first check the if 2 is in it 3 times, and so on that would be a much better approach and not that hart to implement you add a while (number%prime == 0) count++ when you leave that loop you check the count when not dividable by 3 you divide it. That would indeed be much faster

Comment: As (but the comment seems removed) somebody pointed out you can do it much more effective if you list the primes one by one